# How to find an editor for a statistics book?

Tags: writing, statistics, copy-editing

I am writing and self-publishing a book on statistics. More specifically, it is titled "The general linear model: Assumptions, violations and remedies (or what to do wen your dependent variable won't behave).

I have a general editor, but she knows nothing about statistics. I'm looking for someone to edit the statistical part.

Comment: You might be able to pay an under appreciated graduate student.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want that editor to do for you?

Comment: He/she should check formulas and such, make sure I haven't messed up somehow and comment on the topics and flow of the book.

Comment: Peter, I'd be happy to get in contact. I probably wouldn't be willing to proofread formulas (or you probably wouldn't be willing to pay me as I think appropriate) and if grad students are your intended audience I think you'll need one of those anyways. But if feel early feedback from someone from natural sciences (including a bit of health) would be helpful, send me an email (see my profile).

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for an editor? It sounds more like peer reviewer to me.

Comment: @cbeleites I tried to send you e-mail but it bounced back to me

Answer (score 3):

Students can make good people to give you advice. If you pick someone who already has the knowledge they can probably give you good feedback on how what you say will work, assuming this is a text and not a professional work.

Graduate students in the field are often needing a bit of extra money and can often be recruited to help, especially if you also give them an acknowledgement. They are also good for providing solutions for exercises that you might include.

However, even advanced undergraduates can verify a book, both for readability at the level you are aiming for and for pointing out where they don't understand the formulas and technical terms you use. That can be especially valuable.

You are wise not to depend solely on your own reading. It is too easy to "see" what you think you wrote, rather than what you actually wrote. And for a textbook, someone who has taken the course in the not too distant past can have a valuable viewpoint.

I assume, of course, that you don't need someone to actually make corrections, as that may be beyond some students. You can do that yourself, certainly, as long as you learn where there are issues that should be addressed.